# jquery Mobile popup dialog dismissible on options doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

jquerymobile 1.30 + jquery 1.91

```
//dismissible doesn't apply
 $("#popupDialogCategoriesButton").click(function (e) {
                $("#popupDialogCategories").popup("open", { dismissible: false })
            });


//dismissible does apply , set it after open
     $("#popupDialogCategoriesButton").click(function (e) {
            $("#popupDialogCategories").popup('open');
            $("#popupDialogCategories").popup("option", "dismissible", false);
            });
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZuV7p/ you should add `data-dismissible="false"` to the popup markup.

Comment: Now you can use `.popup("open", { dismissible: false })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

In order to open the `popup` and change the value of `dismissible` at the same time, add `data-dismissible=""` with no value/blank to the `popup` markup, then you can change it to either `true` or `false`.

Markup

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-dismissible="">
 <p>To close me, hit the button below.
 <p> <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">close</a>
</div>
```

JQM

```
$(document).on('click', '#openpopup', function () {
 $('#popupBasic').popup('open', { dismissible: false });
});
```

You have two options:

**1) To define the value of `data-dismissible` in the `popup` markup.**

Markup

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-dismissible="false">
 <p>To close me, hit the button below.<p>
 <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">close</a>
</div>

<a href="#" data-role="button" id="openpopup">click me</a> // open it
```

JQM

```
$(document).on('click', '#openpopup', function() {
 $('#popupBasic').popup("open");
});
```

**2) Change `dismissible` value before/after opening it.**

Markup

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
 <p>To close me, hit the button below.<p>
 <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">close</a>
</div>

<a href="#" data-role="button" id="openpopup">click me</a> // open it
```

JQM

```
$(document).on('click', '#openpopup', function() {
 $('#popupBasic').popup("open");
 $('#popupBasic').popup({ dismissible: false });
});
```

[Live example - updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZuV7p/4/)

Comment: yea thanks , data-dismissible="false" works but I dont wanna use it ,  why the open,option doesn't work? I'm using Option 2 , after option event $('#popupBasic').popup({ dismissible: false });

Comment: add `data-dismissible=""` blank with no value and it will work the way you want. check this update http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZuV7p/3/

Comment: workaround :) I'v checked other options like shadow and corners in the way I want .. doesn't work either..  well w/e :)

Comment: i have updated the answer, this should work now. i'll check about the rest.

Comment: Yea, it is weird they dont work inline with `dismissible`. I'll investigate more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and my solution is to list all the options down below

```
$("#popupDialog").popup({history: false});
$("#popupDialog").popup({corners: false});
$("#popupDialog").popup({shadow: false});
$("#popupDialog").popup("open");
```

It's not good looking but working well.