# How do I programmatically adjust options for a panel in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, function, css, jquery-mobile

When going through the docs on JQuery Mobile for panels, it provides the following as the example for how to open a panel:

```
$( "#idofpanel" ).panel( "open" , optionsHash );
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what that looks like. For example, I'd like to make the position be on the right. That'll work if I use the data-position attribute but not so much trying to manipulate it via javascript. It continues to open the panel but ignore my option overrides.

The most correct (imo) looking thing I've tried:

```
$('#rightpanel').panel(
    "open",
    {
        position: "right",
        animate: false,
        dismissable: false
    }
);
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on this. Thanks! :)

Comment: opening a panel and changing its options inline, would not work. it happens to popups too. check this question, its somehow similar to yours. [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435934/jquery-mobile-popup-dialog-dismissible-on-options-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then I need to disappoint you, jQuery Mobile is problematic peace of framework, not to mention panels first appeared in last jQuery Mobile version. And that makes them buggy.

Currently, from your example, only position option work, and ONLY if it is set before panel is opened.

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/znygq/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#openpanel', function() {              
        $('#rightpanel').panel({ position: "right"});       
        $('#rightpanel').panel("open");          
    });        
});
```

Comment: Hrmm, your syntax make it actually show on the right but still appears to be buggy. It will open on the right but isn't correctly displaying the panel contents when using this method. The data-position="right" seems to not have this issue so will stick with that. Any suggestions on frameworks that are a bit more baked WRT panels that slide in youtube style?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any other framework with this complex panel configuration options. Tell me why don't you set everything through attributes. Another option is to create panel dynamically from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#rightpanel').panel(
    "open",
    {
      options: {
        position: "right",
        animate: false,
        dismissable: false
      }
    }
);
```

I like your way better, but it looks like this is how they do it on the demo site.

Answer (score 0):

if you set classes manually you can do the best but in order to future improvement on JQM maybe you can do both for now:

I just improved [Gajotres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440394/how-do-i-programmatically-adjust-options-for-a-panel-in-jquery-mobile#15440655)'s answer and result in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gigapedia/znygq/38/)

```
var panel = $("#rightpanel"),
    DEFAULT = {
    POSITION: {
        left: {type: "left"},
        right: {type: "right"}
    },
    DISPLAY: {
        overlay: { type: "overlay" , className: "ui-panel-display-overlay"},
        reveal: { type: "reveal" , className: "ui-panel-display-reveal"},
        push: { type: "push" , className: "ui-panel-display-push"}
    }
},
lastState = {
    display: DEFAULT.DISPLAY.push,
    position: DEFAULT.POSITION.left
};

function options (key, value) {
    return panel.panel("option", key, value);
}

function position (pos) {
    // { left | right }
    if (
        DEFAULT.POSITION[pos] && 
        DEFAULT.POSITION[pos].type !== lastState.position.type
    ){
        panel.panel("close");
        lastState.position = DEFAULT.POSITION[pos]
        panel
            .toggleClass("ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-position-right");
        return options("position", pos);
    }
}

function display (disp) {
    // { overlay | reveal | push }
    if (
        DEFAULT.DISPLAY[disp] &&
        DEFAULT.DISPLAY[disp].type !== lastState.display.type
    ) {
        panel.panel("close");
        lastState.display = DEFAULT.DISPLAY[disp]
        panel
            .removeClass("ui-panel-display-reveal ui-panel-display-overlay ui-panel-display-push")
            .addClass(display.className);
        return options("display", disp);
    }
}


$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#openpanel', function() {
        position("right");
        panel.panel("open")
    });
});
```